# What data set was used Gene Expression Data of Postmortem Tissues?

Tags: ngs, public-databases, unsupervised-learning

I want to run the experiments "*Sample Application to Genotype-Tissue Expression (GTEx) Project Gene Expression Data of Postmortem Tissues*" mentioned in "*Enter the Matrix: Factorization Uncovers Knowledge from Omics*" by Stein-O'Brien et.al [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952518301240)

The paper metioned

> dataset from postmortem samples in the GTEx project [42] (Figure 3).
> Specifically, we select a subset of GTEx data containing 12 brain
> tissues in the GTEx data for seven individuals for which we had
> previously performed only NMF analysis [41] (codes are provided in the
> supplemental information online).

I check with https://gtexportal.org/home/datasets and assumed that the paper used the `GTEx Analysis V6`.

But which files do I need to download? I am computer scientist I am unsure which ones contain the `brain  tissues`

Further I found

```
Brain_Anterior_cingulate_cortex_BA24_Analysis_cis-eQTLs.txt.gz  1.5G
Brain_Caudate_basal_ganglia_Analysis_cis-eQTLs.txt.gz   1.9G
Brain_Cerebellar_Hemisphere_Analysis_cis-eQTLs.txt.gz   1.7G
Brain_Cerebellum_Analysis_cis-eQTLs.txt.gz  1.9G
Brain_Cortex_Analysis_cis-eQTLs.txt.gz  1.9G
```

But I am unsure which one was used in the paper